# Risc-V simulator with Instruction by instruction API

Tags: api, simulator, riscv

Is there a Risc-V simulator that provides a C++ API to execute instruction by instruction? and API to set registers? I am looking also at the ability to "undo" instructions for "branch not taken" simulation.

Comment: Well, I want to use a RISC-V simulator as a library via an API. My C++ program generates RISC-V assembler instructions and needs to execute these instructions on the simulator at run time and then get the RISC-V state (Regs, mem...) from the simulator after each instruction execution.

Comment: [Spike](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim) is probably worth a look.